# TypeError: common_1.ValidationPipe is not a constructor

Tags: npm, nest, class-validator

Good night everyone. Im with a problem witch i cant use class-validator

I didnt find any one link what could help me

my app.main is like that

```
import {ValidationPipe} from '@nestjs/common';
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Lama-test API')
    .setDescription('Making an APIREST for Lama')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

But when ill run my api I get the follow trouble:
"common_1.ValidationPipe is not a constructor"

Comment: can you please share the complete error stack.

Comment: for sure @HarshSingla. Follow: C:\Users\clemi\Desktop\lama-test\src\main.ts:15
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
                     ^
TypeError: common_1.ValidationPipe is not a constructor
    at bootstrap (C:\Users\clemi\Desktop\lama-test\src\main.ts:15:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: can you please also share app.module file. I am wondering if the validationpipe has been provided properly to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

this question was solved. I had made something wrong in node_modules. So I a re-intalled it and now is working